# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Field 5408 in record is not a valid float: inactive [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to import data from a csv file with 16772 rows, each containing 5409 attributes per line, 5408 of the attributes are float values--I got the data from this [link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/p53+Mutants). However, the very last feature in each row is a string: either "active" or "inactive", I made the following tensorflow program to import the data:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
defaults = ([tf.float32] * 5408) + ([tf.string] * 1)
dataset = tf.contrib.data.CsvDataset(['K9.data'],defaults)
print(list(dataset.take(1))
```

I get an error message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Field 5408 in record is not a valid float: inactive [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```